# Adding DKIM Signature on Emails

Tags: python, dkim

I have a script in python that sends an email from my domain. I have the public key inputted in the DNS records of my domain already. Is there anyway for me to add a DKIM signature to my email through a python script? As I do not use a mail service like PostFix, I am unable to configure the server to add the DKIM signature. I have been searching for a solution but I am unable to find one

Comment: Did you check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22833719/manually-signing-an-email-with-dkim-in-python

Comment: Just did, but its a little confusing as I am not familiar with python.
sig = dkim.sign(text, 'default', '<mydomain.here>', private_key, include_headers=headers)
Where can I append the above code?